# Touch file then write to it in Node

Tags: node.js, io, coffeescript, touch, libuv

How do I touch a file before writing to it?

#### Attempt

```coffee
fs   = require 'fs'
os   = require 'os'
path = require 'path'


json_filepath = path.join os.tempdir(), 'cache', 'foo.json'

module.exports = (cb) ->
    fs.open json_filepath, 'w', 438, (err) -> # Touch, also tried with node-touch
        return cb err if err?
        fs.writeFile json_filepath, {foo: 'bar'}, {}, (err) ->
            #console.error 'Error writing cache: ', err
            cb err
```

#### Error

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/tmp/cache/foo.json']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/tmp/cache/foo.json' }
```

Which is a POSIX error ([linux manpage](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=errno), additionally implemented for Windows, e.g.: [in libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/src/win/error.c#L133)). It means: *No such file or directory*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to open a file before calling `fs.writeFile()`?  That is the wrong procedure and is likely causing at least part of your problem.

You should JUST call `fs.writeFile()`.  That will create the file, write to it and close it all in one call.  Opening the file first in `w` mode will likely cause a conflict with `fs.writeFile()` since the file is already open for writing elsewhere.  Further, you never close the file you opened, thus leaking a file handle.

Just call `fs.writeFile()` with no `fs.open()` beforehand.  That's how `fs.writeFile()` is written to work.  One function call to do it all.

If you still get `ENOENT` after removing the `fs.open()` and you've cleared any orphaned file handles, then the remaining issue is likely that your path doesn't exist or you don't have the proper privileges on that path.

FYI, the path specified by:

```
path.join(os.tempdir(), "cache")
```

will not automatically exist.  That would have to be something you created.

Answer (score 2):

To answer original question

```
fs.writeFileSync('sporks','','utf8','a')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this? [File System Exists](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path)

`fs.existsSync(path);`

returns true if exists.

Comment: I have that in another part of my code. If the cache exists it is used, otherwise a bunch of stuff happens to populate contents to fill the cache with. Which is the test-case that I've shown.

Comment: question: is there a `tmp` folder or `cache` folder exists?

Comment: Yes, that folder does exist

Comment: have you check the privileges on that folder?

Comment: Watch out for race conditions.